# Is it possible to add a button in the IPhone Calendar Event creation/edit view?

Tags: iphone, calendar, customization

I want to customize the IPhone Calendar Event view by adding a new button.
The purpose is to allow the user to click on this button and then browse to select in a list the name of  a friend. The name should then be written in the "note" field of the calendar event.

Is it possible to modify such standard view?

Thanks
Charles

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. The iPhone SDK doesn't provide any official way to access calendars or the Calendar app from 3rd party applications.

Comment: true, but surely somebody out there has built a calendar XIB and shared it with the rest of the world no?

Comment: Maybe, and I'm all for a decent Cocoa Touch calendar kit, but that doesn't mean it'll be able to integrate with the iPhone's native calendar application. The original question was asking if the standard "add calendar event" view could be modified, and the answer is no.